# how to append a extra character to a variable that contain string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have struck in a issue that appending a special character to a variable that contain the value from a `textbox`. I have used `.append()` function to append a character but I getting error in console as append is not a function can anyone help me out from this issue

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
 <input type="textbox" id="textbox"/>
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '.button', function(){  

var demo=$('#textbox').val();
var demoapp=demo.append("^");
console.log(demoapp);

 });
    });
</script>
```

### Can Any one help me out from this

https://jsfiddle.net/pxdc9g0f/6/

Comment: Guess `append` isn't the right method to do that. Do you just need to append it to demo value?

Comment: is this what you want`? https://jsfiddle.net/pxdc9g0f/11/ please note you havent included jquery

Comment: Without jQuery (which is overkill for what you need), you can use `document.querySelector('#textbox').value += "^"` or `document.getElementById('textbox').value += "^"`. Also, `textbox` is not a valid input type. The correct one in `text`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do normal string concatenation instead of using any library (like use used .append() )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.button', function() {

    var demo = $('#textbox').val();
    var demoapp = demo + "^";
    alert(demoapp);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <input type="textbox" id="textbox" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var demoapp=demo.append("^");`, use `var demoapp=demo+"^";`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `append` on a value, but from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):
 *Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.*

If you just need a string concatenation, you should try something like this:

```
var demo=$('#textbox').val();
var demoapp=demo + "^";
alert(demoapp);
```

If you want to edit the `#textbox` value, then you should try this:

```
var demo=$('#textbox');
demo.val(demo.val() + '^');
alert(demo.val());
```